# Fullcalendar JSON event feed not working with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

For some reason I cannot get my JSON feed (which is assembled via php) to show up on my Fullcalendar plugin. The JSON is valid and works great if I hardcode it as an event source. But when it's being fetched via URL, nothing shows! I know several people have had this same problem, but either it has not been answered yet or their solution doesn't seem to work for me.  Any help on this is much appreciated, as I have stared at this for two days and can't catch a break.

Here is my js

```
    $(function()
    {


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    minTime: 7,
    maxTime: 20,
    slotMinutes: 15,
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
element.find('.fc-event-title').html(event.title);
},
    events: { 
    url: "http://mywebsite.com/js/schedule_feed.php",
    data: {locationID: <?=$locationID?>},
    type: "POST",
    error: function () {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
},
});

});
```

And here is my php:

```
     <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydatabase") or die(mysql_error());
$query = "select schedule.schedule_id, schedule.type, schedule.show, schedule.schedule_date, patients.fname, patients.lname
from schedule
LEFT JOIN patients
ON schedule.patient_id=patients.patient_id
WHERE patients.locationID='".$_POST['locationID']."'";

$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$events = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['schedule_id'];
$eventsArray['title'] =  ucfirst(strtolower($row['lname'])) . ", " . ucfirst(strtolower($row['fname'])); //. $isNewCustomer;
    $eventsArray['start'] = strtotime($row['schedule_date']);
    $timestamp = strtotime($row['schedule_date']) + 60*30;
    $eventsArray['end'] = $timestamp;

    $eventsArray['backgroundColor'] = '#999';
    $eventsArray['textColor'] = '#fff';
    $eventsArray['url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php/schedule/edit_appt/' . $row['schedule_id'];
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = false;
    $eventsArray['editable'] = false;
    $eventsArray['timeFormat'] = 'h(:mm)';
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}
echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

Once again, if I type in my php url directly into the browser, it provides me with valid JSON.  If I copy that JSON feed from the browser and hardcode it directly into the JS...it works! What the heck is going on?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: i had the same problem. finally gave up. It gives an ajax error.

Comment: yeah I get an error too.  I know I have gotten this to work before, it's just really frustrating.  Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I've even slimmed down the code to only contain the bare minimum...still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!!!  For anyone who runs into this same issue, it has something to do with cross domain ajax.  You can read about it on the following link:
[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I just added this code to the top of my php script:

```
    <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mydomain.com'); ?>
```